# Calculating the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^3$ minus a circle using Van Kampen and these particular open sets

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I know this has been answered [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148185/calculating-the-fundamental-group-of-mathbb-r3-setminus-a-for-a-a-circle) but I’m looking for a calculation using the following open sets:

I want to calculate $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus C)$, where $C$ is the circle parameterized by $(\cos(t), \sin (t), 0)$. I want to choose $U_1$ as $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus (C \cup \Delta)$, where $\Delta$ is the $z$ axis, and $U_2$ as the open cylinder centered in the $z$ axis with radius $1$. I already know from a previous calculation that $\pi_1(U_1)=\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus (C \cup \Delta))=\mathbb{Z}^2$, and $\pi_1(U_2)$ should be trivial. I also think $U_1\cap U_2$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$ (right?) so applying Van Kampen I get something like

$$\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus C)=\mathbb{Z}^2 *_{\mathbb{Z}}\{1\}$$
…which I’m not sure how to calculate (I’m still learning about amalgamated products, see [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4474254/help-with-amalgated-product-calculating-pi-1-mathbbrp2)).

But I think the answer should be $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus C)=\mathbb{Z}$, so I’m not sure if my reasoning is correct.

Comment: Do you mean $U_1 \cap U_2$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$? Regardless, you're very close!

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Yes, that’s what I meant!

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thank you! Is $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus C)=\mathbb{Z}^2 *_\mathbb{Z} \{e\}$ correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're so close!

You're entirely correct that $U_1 \cap U_2$ is homotopic to $S^1$, so that (writing $X = \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus C$) van kampen's theorem buys us

$$
\pi_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2 \ast_\mathbb{Z} 1
$$

The question, then, is how to show this amalgamated free product is actually $\mathbb{Z}$. More importantly, we should be able to say what the *geometric meaning* of this $\mathbb{Z}$ is. After all, it should tell us something about loops in $X$!

---

The intuitive idea of van kampen's theorem is this:
Loops in $X$ decompose as products of loops in $U_1$ and loops in $U_2$.

After all, if a loop goes through $U_1$ and $U_2$, then it goes through the intersection (where the basepoint is assumed to be) so we can just pinch our loop into one loop in $U_1$ and one loop in $U_2$. In a picture:

[image: a loop using U_1 and U_2]

we can "pinch" $\gamma$ inside the intersection $U_1 \cap U_2$ in order to break it up into two loops (whose product is homotopic to $\gamma$:

[image: splitting gamma into two loops]

This tells us that every loop in $U_1 \cup U_2$ can be written as a product of loops in $U_1$ and loops in $U_2$. Of course, these loops might not commute! So we're inspired to look at the free product
$\pi_1(U_1) \ast \pi_1(U_2)$.

There's just one hangup: What if there are loops which lie *entirely* inside $U_1 \cap U_2$? These are the same loop in $X$, but we're "double counting" them, once in $\pi_1(U_1)$ and once in $\pi_1(U_2)$.

We can solve this by taking a quotient to *force* these loops to be the same! That is, we look at the quotient

$$
\frac{\pi_1(U_1) \ast \pi_1(U_2)}{\iota_1 \gamma = \iota_2 \gamma \text{ for $\gamma \in \pi_1(U_1 \cap U_2)$}}
$$

where $\iota_k$ is the natural maps $\pi_1(U_1 \cap U_2) \to \pi_1(U_k)$ by viewing a loop in $U_1 \cap U_2$ as a loop in the bigger space $U_k$.

This construction comes up surprisingly frequently, so we give it an abbreviated name. Since we're [amalgamating](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amalgamate) the two different "copies" of $\pi_1(U_1 \cap U_2)$, we call this the *amalgamated* free product

$$\pi_1(U_1) \ast_{\pi_1(U_1 \cap U_2)} \pi_1(U_2)$$

If you want more information about this, see an old answer of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4143523/in-van-kampen-s-theorem-what-happens-to-the-loops-not-in-pi-1u-alpha-cap-u).

---

Concretely, though, how do we *work* with an amalgamated free product?

Well, the free product $G \ast H$ is the group with generators $g \in G$ and $h \in H$ where we remember how to multiply elements in $G$ and $H$ separately. So in the amalgamated free product, we just impose additional relations saying that $g = h$ whenever $g = \iota_1 \gamma$ and $h = \iota_2 \gamma$.

So for us, we have $\pi_1(U_1)$, which is generated by the two loops $\alpha$ and $\beta$

[image: A picture of U_1]

and of course, $\pi_1(U_2) = 1$, since it's contractible

[image: a cylinder]

But (as you've noticed) the *intersection* is not trivial. Indeed we see $\pi_1 (U_1 \cap U_2)$ is generated by $\beta$.

[image: U_1 cap U_2]

To compute the amalgamated free product, we need to know the image of this $\beta$ in $\pi_1(U_1)$ and $\pi_1(U_2)$. Notice that, inside of $X$, this is the same loops as what we were calling $\beta$ in $\pi_1(U_1)$. Of course, inside of $U_2$ this loop is contractible, and its image is $1$.

At last, then, we see the amalgamated free product is

$$
\begin{align}
\pi_1(U_1) \ast_{\pi_1(U_1 \cap U_2)} \pi_1(U_2) 
&\cong
\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle \ast_{\langle \beta \rangle} \langle 1 \rangle \\
&\cong
\langle \alpha, \beta, 1 \mid \beta = 1 \rangle \\
&\cong 
\langle \alpha \rangle \\
&\cong \mathbb{Z}
\end{align}
$$

Which is exactly what we expected!

Moreover, we've learned that the fundamental group of $X$ is generated by $\alpha$, the loop which goes around the copy of $C$ we removed. This is also what we expect geometrically, which is a good sanity check!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Wow great answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help ^_^